# ERROR: Unidentified (Riley riddle)

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> Riddle me this 
>  My prefix the Bard says when he means soon 
>  My suffix a rodent without its tail 
>  In my infix a lady her torch uphold high 
>  Who am I?

Hint 1:

> The last line IS part of the riddle, You are supposed to answer the Riley, not the question in the last line

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My prefix the Bard says when he means soon

> [anon](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anon)

My suffix a rodent without its tail

> mous(e)

In my infix a lady her torch uphold high

> NY?

Who am I?

> anonymous

Comment: For the infix rot13(Fgnghr bs yvoregl vf va AL Pvgl)

Comment: You got it right so quick... Why.....  +1 plus the tick to you! Well done!